# На первый взгляд простая анимация

Tags: javascript, html, анимация

Есть задача: У большого заголовка есть красивый андерлайн с завитушками в png, который я цепляю просто блоком ниже.

Есть 2 вида андерлайна:

1) прижат слева или справа;

2) второй по центру.

Нужно их сделать плавно появляющимися из точки.

Вот прижата слева:[image: вот прижатая слева].

А вот центральная:  [image: центрированная].

Проблемы с боковыми нет. Я просто делаю их бекграундом выровненным по сторонам и делаю чтобы блок в котором он плавно рос от 0 до 100%. Казалось бы сделай тоже самое с центральным просто отцентрировав. Но появляется косяк. Ветка начинает дико дрыгаться. Мои предположения что блок растет по пиксильно и центрируется то влево то в право на пиксель ну и это короче очень заметно. Что можете подсказать?

Comment: пожалуйста в вопросе напишите Ваш код, чтобы можно было увидеть проблему наяву.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте центральную разрезать на две части и анимировать также как и боковые.

Comment: черт) это гениально) я сначала думал наложить два блока сверху) и ими управлять, хорошо попробую отпишу. Костылек правда, но можно попробовать)

Comment: @burn не стоит боятся костылей, ведь большинство программистов на них и учатся) но также не стоит ими злоупотреблять.

Comment: в общем очевидное решение, но почему-то мне оно сразу в голову не пришло, спасибо!